# Why drop down keeps old values upon each postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am filling drop down list when i click a value in another drop down list e.g. country cities relation but problem is that it loads relevant values upo clicking but if i change value in parent drop down then it appends old values too e.g. if i select U.S.A in parent drop down then it loads cities i.e. NY, Washington, LasVegas etc but if i click Pakistan then it loads Pakistani cities plus US cities too, like appending, why ?

Code:

```
 protected void drpAgainstDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//against district drop down selected index changed event
    {
        if (txtSelectedID.Text != "")
        {
            MyComplaints obj = new MyComplaints();
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(drpAgainstDistrict.SelectedValue);
            DataSet ds = obj.SelectHomePoliceStaions(ID);

            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataTextField = "PsName";
            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataValueField = "ID";
            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataBind();
            HiddenFieldShowHideButtons.Value = "True";
        }
        else 
        {
            MyComplaints obj = new MyComplaints();
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(drpAgainstDistrict.SelectedValue);
            DataSet ds = obj.SelectHomePoliceStaions(ID);

            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataTextField = "PsName";
            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataValueField = "ID";
            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            drpAgainstPoliceStation.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

.aspx

```
<label>Relevant District</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpAgainstDistrict" runat="server"
                  Width="178px" AutoPostBack="True"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpAgainstDistrict_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<label>Relevant Police Station</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpAgainstPoliceStation" runat="server"
                  Width="178px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` specified. The documentation states that this "indicates whether list items are cleared before data binding", in your case it will append list items without first clearing the list.

Source: [ListControl.AppendDataBoundItems Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: There's nothing to do. You asked why items were appended, I pointed out the property that appended the items. If you do not want them appended, either remove it or set it to false.

Answer (score 2):

Because of `ViewState`. Just clear the Dropdownlist. `yourDropdownList.Items.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to wrap cascading drop down lists with UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

Because of AppendDataBoundItems="true" change to AppendDataBoundItems="false"